# remove button from second div which will same id(class) button in first div html,jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove `<button>`.

for example remove second `<div>` tag `<button>` when i have to click on second `<div>` tag `<button>` like `<div class="demo2">`

```
 <div class="demo1">
  <button id="btn1" class="btn1">Add1</button>
 </div>
 <div class="demo2">
   <button id="btn1" class="btn1">Add1</button>
 </div>
 <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script><script>
      $(document).ready(function()
     {
        alert("aaa");
        $("#demo2 .btn1").remove();
     });
 </script>
```

**I try this Code:**

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function()       
      {
           $("#btn1").remove(); 
       });
</script>
```

it will remove first `<button>` but I want to remove second `<div>`
 and `<button>`

Comment: same problem ..

Comment: this answer is useful click button in my question ? reply

Answer (score 1):

You need `.demo2` and not `#demo2` since `demo2` is a `class` and 
`not an id`

```js
     
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
        alert("aaa");
        $(".demo2 .btn1").remove();
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo1">
        <button id="btn1" class="btn1">Add1</button>
     </div>
     <div class="demo2">
        <button id="btn1" class="btn1">Add2</button>
     </div>
```

This can also be a little more complicated cond=sider you don't know which id are repeating, in that case you can use a loop like below

```js
$(document).ready(function()
     {
        $('.demo1 button').each(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          $('.demo2 button').each(function() {
            if($(this).attr('id') === id) {
              $(this).remove();
            }
          })
        })
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo1">
        <button id="btn1" class="btn1">Add1</button>
        <button id="btn2" class="btn1">Add1</button>
     </div>
     <div class="demo2">
        <button id="btn1" class="btn">Add2</button>
         <button id="btn2" class="btn">Add2</button>
        <button id="btn3" class="btn">Add2</button>
     </div>
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out the solution. Let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but firstly you can't use an the same id CSS tag twice. If it's just to remove the second button after the alert then just change the id and remove that single button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("aaa");
  $("#btn2").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo1">
  <button id="btn1" class="btn1">Add1</button>
</div>
<div class="demo2">
  <button id="btn2" class="btn1">Add1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the context of the i'th element having the same selector:

```
getElementAt(selector, i) {
    return $(selector + ":eq(" + i + ")");
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
getElementAt("[id=btn1]", 1).remove();
```

The `#` id operator returns the first element having the given `id`, as the browser assumes that a unique identifier can be present maximum once in a document. Therefore your HTML is invalid and you should fix it, but if you do not have time now to do that, you can use `[id=btn1]` instead of `#`. You can also use `document.querySelectorAll("[id=btn1]")[i]` if you like.